# How to draw overlaying shapes in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to recreate a UI in flutter that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4zdq.jpg) I need to get this shapes in the position they appear in the image above, I did some research and came across Flutter Custom Paint, tried checking for tutorials on how to use it to achieve this design but can't find anything that points me in the right direction. Please is there anyway in flutter to recreate [this UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTG71.jpg)?

Comment: yep, you need a class that extends `CustomPainter` and  inside `paint` method you have to call `Canvas.drawCircle` twice

Answer (score 0):

Instead of complicating things

You can use stack for overlapping

And for that circles you can use containers with borderradius

and using positioned widget to position the circles based on your need

MORE THAN THIS

you can export that design as an image and use

Stack{

children[

THAT IMAGE,

YOUR UI,

]}